# RegEx to find either i=(integer) or itemtype_id=(integer) in string for 301 redirects

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect, integer

I've got a big list of 'old' URL's using query strings to point to a specific item in an old database which I would like to convert to 'new' static URL's. I need a RegEx to find either i=(a certain integer value) OR itemtype_id=(the same integer value) within a sourc URL, which I will then convert to the new static URL using a table of integer value<->static URL's that I've got available. For example:

- www.mydomain.com?i=2000&c=20
- www.mydomain.com?itemype_id=2000&category_id=20
- www.mydomain.com?i=2000
- www.mydomain.com?itemtype_id=2000

*The c= or category_id= parts from the old URL are irrelevant.*

For all of the 4 above cases, I would like to match the result 2000 to a specific URL from my static URL list, say 2000 is www.mynewdomain/mynewstaticitem.html

Anyone? Any help would be much appreciated as I am stuck here!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule in site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)(?:i|itemype_id)=2000(?:&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ /http://www.mynewdomain/mynewstaticitem.html? [L,R=301]
```

Pattern `(?:^|&)(?:i|itemype_id)=2000(?:&|$)` will match `i=2000` OR `itemype_id=2000` anywhere in query string.